# Screeps - Property in Memory resets

Tags: javascript, screeps

I have a problem with Memory. It should to store all my data (not objects) but it resets from time to time.
This is example:

```
Memory.creeps_idx = 0;   

module.exports.loop = function () {

    console.log("c_idx:", Memory.creeps_idx, Game.time);

    if(Memory.creeps_idx==0)
    {
        Memory.creeps_idx+=1;
    }    
}
```

And this is output from console.

```
[13:41:01]c_idx: 0 1115
[13:41:03]c_idx: 1 1116
[13:41:05]c_idx: 0 1117
[13:41:07]c_idx: 1 1118
[13:41:09]c_idx: 1 1119
[13:41:11]c_idx: 1 1120
[13:41:13]c_idx: 1 1121
[13:41:15]c_idx: 1 1122
[13:41:17]c_idx: 0 1123
[13:41:19]c_idx: 1 1124
[13:41:21]c_idx: 1 1125
[13:41:23]c_idx: 1 1126
[13:41:25]c_idx: 1 1127
```

Can you tell me why creeps_idx changes value to 0? (This was tested in simulator)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, anything outside of module.exports.loop is run once every few ticks.  This is why creep_idx gets reset to in your original example, and why your solution works.

> What is new here is the way you main module is executed. In the old-style architecture, it is executed every tick, and every module required from it is also executed every tick. In the new architecture, your main module should contain the module.exports.loop function which is executed in a game loop, while the rest of the main module contents are executed only after a new global is instantiated.

http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/204825672-New-main-loop-architecture

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution myself.

```
module.exports.loop = function () {
    if (!Memory.creeps_idx) Memory.creeps_idx = 0;
    console.log("c_idx:", Memory.creeps_idx, Game.time);

    if(Memory.creeps_idx==0)
    {
        Memory.creeps_idx+=1;
    }
}
```